# Text in OpenGL on an Object

Tags: android, text, opengl-es

I'm developing a sphere which should show text at certain positions. I tried it with CBFG and it's API, but I just counld saw a text at a fixed position on the screen. But I need to have a dynamic text which I can move around with a onTouchListener. With my Sphere it works fine, also with a Bitmap on it, but how can i make it with the text?

Comment: sounds like you want to generate a texture at runtime which contains the rendered text, then you put the generated texture on the sphere.  you need to render the text into a bitmap and then use that as the texture on the sphere.

Comment: mmh okay but I need to match text position and the position on the sphere (depends on th degree like a compass).. how is that possible? Is there a nice example?

Comment: you control the position/orientation of the texture on the sphere using texture coordinates.  the texture coordinates assign locations in the texture to vertices in the geometry.  probably any sample on texture mapping should get you started.  you'll want info on mapping a texture to a sphere, on texture coordinates to control how the texture maps onto the sphere, and then also info on rendering to a texture image at runtime.

Comment: Okay that sound logical.. Do you have maybe a nice example for it?

Comment: I don't have one which exactly covers what your'e trying to do.  You might want to look through the NeHe tutorials [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/).  I believe there's a texture mapping tutorial and a text drawing tutorial.  I've done the text-on-a-sphere myself, though I didn't need the precise control, so I know the general approach I described is correct.  Search for texture mapping examples and render to texture as well.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. With your idea I could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

```
TextView textV = new TextView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(128, 128);
        textV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textV.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        textV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textV.setText(text);

        textV.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( textV.getLayoutParams().width, textV.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        textV.layout(0, 0, textV.getLayoutParams().width, textV.getLayoutParams().height);
        textV.draw(c);
        textV.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

With that code I'll get a Bitmap which I can use as a texture ;-)